# How to change ext4 primary partition to logical

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

This is how my partitions look like. They were created in a very lame way I admit:)
[image: Partitions]

My primary goal here is to be able to have another primary partition for 3rd OS but for this I need to do something as I unwisely created `/home` partition as primary.

Most likely I will remove and re-create swap and windows partitions (reinstalling windows).

So the only way how to achieve this is for me to somehow change `sda2` partition to logical.
I don't mind doing anything except reinstalling Linux on `sda1` and losing data on `sda2.

What are my options here? 
Is it for example possible to remove everything except `sda1` and `sda2` then somehow clone `sda2`to the new logical partition of newly created extented partition?

Comment: Are you sure you need an extended partition? The laptop I am using here has 9 partitions, none extended. It came with 7 partitions, courtesy of W8, and I found no difficulty using **parted** to add two more for Ubuntu and Swap.

Comment: @AFH you are likely using GPT partitioning.  The above is MSDOS partitioning, so only supports four primary partitions.

Comment: @Paul - you may well be right: I have never needed to investigate on this machine. In which case LeNoob needs either to convert to GPT (if each OS supports it) or to save a partition by using a swap file instead of a swap partition (unless there is a need to hibernate): **/dev/sda4** can be moved to the end of the disc, and **/dev/sda3** can then be recreated to fill all the available space.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert primary to logical and vice-versa using my [FixParts program.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) Many Linux distributions provide it in the `gdisk` or `gptfdisk` package; the command name is `fixparts`. There are some caveats, though; namely, you need to have at least one free (unallocated) sector immediately preceding *every* to-be-logical partition. It's unclear if you've got such a free sector before your current `/dev/sda2`. If not, the safest way to create such a gap is to use GParted to shrink `/dev/sda1` (that's `/dev/sda1`, *not* `/dev/sda2`) by the smallest amount possible -- probably 1MiB. That will open a gap between `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`, which will enable FixParts to convert `/dev/sda2` from primary to logical. Note that you'll need to do all of this (or at least the GParted operations) from a live CD; GParted won't let you operate on partitions that are currently mounted, as `/dev/sda1` must be if you boot from it.

Answer (score 2):

You have room to move /home back into root.

```
sudo mkdir /home2
sudo rsync -ax /home/ /home2/
sudo umount /home  (you'll need to boot as single user to do this)
sudo rmdir /home
sudo mv /home2 /home
```

Then edit /etc/fstab so that it doesn't mount /home

Then you can delete /dev/sda2 and re-create it as an extended partition.  Note that if the third OS is linux or similar, it doesn't need to be in a primary partition.  Grub can boot it from a logical.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you need to do is just:

- create a new partition from unallocated space
- install a new OS in there
- optionally. repair GRUB and MBR if the 3rd OS is Windows, which more than likely will overwrite MBR with putting only itself to the boot option.